# Velocity: How to make a global array?

Tags: velocity, nvelocity

I have 3 vm files: **f1.vm**, **f2.vm** and **f3.vm** 
in f1.vm I make the array with name **PROTOCOL_VERSIONS**:

```
#set($PROTOCOL_VERSIONS = [])
```

I want to add elements in PROTOCOL_VERSIONS from f2.vm file:

```
#set($success = $PROTOCOL_VERSIONS.add('{"major":1, "minor":0}'))
```

and use the PROTOCOL_VERSIONS array in the f3.vm

```
[
#foreach( $protocolVersion in PROTOCOL_VERSIONS )
{
"header": {
           "upv": $protocolVersion,
          },
}  #if(!$foreach.last) 
, 
#end
#end
]
```

I tried it but unfortunately it does not initialization.
Is it possible ?